# Flutter pod file conflict Fix

Tags: flutter, dart

This is a note to myself for the next time I come across a similar error

I get this error when running `pod install`

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "tau_core":
  In Podfile:
    flutter_sound (from `.symlinks/plugins/flutter_sound/ios`) was resolved to 7.7.1, which depends on
      tau_core (= 7.7.0+1)

    tau_core (= 2.2.0)

None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependencies: `tau_core (= 2.2.0), tau_core (= 7.7.0+1)`.
```

Fixed through:

```
Delete .symlink
delete podfile.lock
delete Pods folder
Make sure there are no dependencies that conflict in PodFile
Make sure in pubspec.yaml dependency is up to date
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
cd ios
pod install
```

Comment: The lower half of the question should instead be an answer. Self-answered questions are fine, just pretend you are asking an actual question and then answer it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps described above but I added an update for the pod repo, make sure to close VSCode after pod install otherwise it can cause errors

```
Delete .symlink
delete podfile.lock
delete Pods folder
Make sure there are no dependencies that conflict in PodFile
Make sure in pubspec.yaml dependency is up to date
flutter clean
flutter pub upgrade
flutter pub get
cd iOS
pod repo update
pod install
```